# How to get text from a JList variable in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get information passed from a `JList` item to one `JFrame` to another. I am having no problem getting the first item in the `JList` transferred over, but as soon as as I add another item, I am not having any luck. Here is an example,

My `JList` includes:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

When the edit button is clicked when John Doe is selected, it automatically assigns the first and last name fields of the last item in the `JList` added (Jane Doe in this case). How can I get it to select the firstNameField at the SELECTED item in the `JList`? I hope this makes sense!

NOTE: IGNORE THE CLUSTERED CODE

```
public class MainJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

DefaultListModel contacts = new DefaultListModel();



/**
 * Creates new form JPanel
 */
public MainJPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    firstNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lastNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    firstNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lastNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    contactList = new javax.swing.JList();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    editButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Contact"));

    firstNameLabel.setText("First Name:");

    lastNameLabel.setText("Last Name:");

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(contactList);

    editButton.setText("Edit");
    editButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            editButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setText("Delete");
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    addButton.setText("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                    .addComponent(editButton)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(deleteButton))
                .addComponent(addButton)))
    );

    jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {addButton, deleteButton, editButton});

    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(addButton)
                .addComponent(deleteButton)
                .addComponent(editButton))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(firstNameLabel)
                .addComponent(lastNameLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lastNameField)
                .addComponent(firstNameField))
            .addGap(6, 6, 6))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(firstNameLabel)
                .addComponent(firstNameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lastNameLabel)
                .addComponent(lastNameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 196, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     contactList.setModel(contacts);
     Object fullName = firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText();
     contacts.addElement(fullName);


}                                         

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete this contact?", "Delete Contact?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            contacts.remove(contactList.getSelectedIndex());
        }     

}                                            

private void editButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    EditJFrame frame = new EditJFrame();

    String editFirstNameField;
    String editLastNameField;
    int index = contactList.getSelectedIndex();

    editFirstNameField = (String) contactList.



    EditJFrame.editFirstNameField.setText(editFirstNameField);
    EditJFrame.editLastNameField.setText(editLastNameField);



    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you share us the whole class?

Comment: Start by taking a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will make your code easier to read.  Second, you may wish to complete the `editFirstNameField = (String) contactList.` line, as it's unclear what you are doing and also how do you determine `editLastNameField`

Comment: It won't compile, as the line `editFirstNameField = (String) contactList.` is incomplete...

Comment: Do you have created a class EditJFrame ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).